# How to combine two different types LiveData with specific attribute updating?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 live data: first is user running score (LiveData, fields - maxSpeed: Float, duration: Long, distance: Float etc.), second is stopwatch (LiveData) I'm keeping in UserScore duration for DB. It's saving when running is over. It's the same as stopwatch, but it's not updating as i want, so i need to update it separatly: UserScore when location is received, Stopwatch value every second. So the problem is:
I need to update my LiveData with fresh running values (maxSpeed, distance), and update duration with fresh timing updates but keep running values the same as before.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use MediatorLiveData and tuples.